# Save JSON/text from URL to local disc in classic ASP

Tags: json, file, asp-classic

I would like to open JSON from external URL but without parsing and pulling data from it, I'd just like to get the JSON to be saved to local file without using FTP. Is that possible?

Should I read a file somehow into a variable first and the save it line by line, I wouldn't like to read JSON and parse it and write it out, I just need the file to be loaded and saved into my local disc. It is JSON file, but the same would be if it would be a program code or text file. Is there any function to state URL and local path to save the file locally?

Comment: You should be able to use the `ADODB.Stream` object to retrieve the [tag:json] then you can use `SaveToFile()` method to save the content of the stream to the File System. Remember that server side code "local paths" will be on the server not on the connected client's machine.

Comment: can you clarify 'local disc' please? server loocal or user local.

Comment: Server local. I would need the file on my server to cache it (so not to call URL every time I need JSON).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a server http request to get the json, eg

```
Set myjson = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    myjson.open "get","http://your-remote-json-source", false
    myjson.send 
    Response.ContentType = "application/json"
```

Then use a file system object to write to your hard drive

```
Set objFileSystem = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myTextFile = objFileSystem.CreateTextFile(Server.Mappath("path/to/directory/jsonfilename.json"),True)
    myTextFile.Write(myjson.responseText)
```